# Separar JSX do componente - React Native

Tags: javascript, mobile, react, react-native, jsx

Existe alguma forma de, no React Native, colocar todo o `JSX` em um arquivo separado sem ter risco de diminuir a performance do `App`?

Tipo o `Angular` que tem um arquivo para o `HTML`, outro para o `CSS` e outro pro `Typescript`.

Edit 1:

Esqueci de mencionar mas, o que eu quero é separar todo o `JSX` e poder utilizar o `state`, `props` e `funções` do componente mesmo assim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não faz muito sentido fazer isso pois o Angular tem uma estrutura de MVC e o react não, o maximo que você pode fazer é criar dois componentes. Um que apenas renderiza components apartir das props e outro que cuida do state e funções

Exemplo em [React](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4q8yv6j8v)

Exemplo em React Native

```
function SomenteJSX(props) {
  return <View>{props.oQueVoceQuiser}</View>;
}

class SomenteStateProps extends React.Component {
  state = {
    oQueVoceQuiser: "hey"
  };

  algumaFuncao = () => console.log("oi");

  render() {
    return (
      <SomenteJSX
        algumaFuncao={this.state.algumaFuncao}
        oQueVoceQuiser={this.state.oQueVoceQuiser}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Mas assim ainda vai ser dificil remover todo o JSX do componente.

Tentar transformar react em uma estrutura MVC não é recomendável. O que eu aconselho é sempre separar o arquivo css do componente.

Comment: Hmm, entendi. Vlw ae brother.